# Cannot open display error when I run sudo gedit on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: sudo, gedit, hadoop, environment

```
solitude@Solitude:~/Desktop$ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(gedit:12631): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: You can't run X11 apps without an X11 display for them to connect to. You might want the `vi` command instead of `gedit` there.

Comment: Related https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/468/why-can-i-not-open-gedit-with-pkexec

Answer (score 2):

You should never use normal sudo to start graphical applications as root. For a complete explanation of this read the answers to this question: [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications).

Nautilus Admin (*nautilus-admin*) is a simple Python extension for the Nautilus file manager that adds some administrative actions to the right-click menu:

- Open as Administrator: opens a folder in a new Nautilus window     running with administrator (root) privileges.
- Edit as Administrator: opens a file in a Gedit window running     with administrator (root) privileges.

To install Nautilus Admin in all  currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
```

An alternative way of editing the same file is to use the system's default text editor program that is designed to run from the terminal without needing any other graphical environment.

```
sudoedit path/to/file
```